# SQL Compact 4.0 and Entity Framework 4.0: Entity Key fixed?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, sql-server-ce

Entity Framework 4.0 wasn't able to create auto-incremented integer identity keys with SQL Compact 3.5, which meant I had to use GUIDs instead--sort of like using a shotgun to kill a fly. Does anyone know if this problem has been fixed with the release of SQL Compact 4.0? Can I use identity keys with EF4 and SQLCE4, or am I still stuck with GUIDs? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this has been fixed in addition to many other improvements: 
- Code First, Paging, Server Generated Keys

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2011/01/12/microsoft-sql-server-compact-4-0-is-available-for-download.aspx